# Smarty cache with database content error

Tags: caching, smarty

i use the smarty cache feature and today i realize my content wasnt refreshed correctly.

i use file caching in smarty with these templates:

- index.html (use this to cache the main page (about 8k)
- list.html (use this to cache about 10 pages - approx 7k each)

i have a custom cms and this allow me to change the main page it does not refresh, i use:

cache_dir & cache feacture correctly because if i delete the cache file, i can see my content refreshed.

is there an easy way to update these files without me deleting them every time i refresh a  page content?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

```
$Smarty = new Smarty();
$Smarty->caching = 1;

$SmartyTemplate = $Smarty->createTemplate($yourfile, $your_cache_id);
// $row = mysql_query("select date_modified from table where ...

if ($SmartyTemplate->isCached() && $SmartyTemplate->cached->timestamp < $row['date_modified']) {
    $Smarty->clearCache($yourfile, $your_cache_id); 
}
$SmartyTemplate->assign('variables', 'data');
$SmartyTemplate->display();
```

Comment: you should have a look at [$smarty->force_cache](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.force.cache.tpl). Set this to true if you "manually" invalidate the cache instead of calling `clearCache()`

Comment: @rodneyrehm why? clear will clear it and force will overwrite it?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

1) When updating anything about index.html or list.html tell Smarty to purge the respective cache using `$smarty->clearCache("index.html");` See [the docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.clear.cache.tpl).

2) Write your own [CacheResource](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.custom.tpl). You can then overload the fetch() and fetchTimestamp() methods to additionally query some database for an external modification time. This way, you don't have to `clearCache()` to inform Smarty that something has changed.

The first option is simpler and quicker to implement. The second option is a global thing, potentially wasting resources on the additional DB connections.